# How these two definitions of category of hypergraph are same?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, hypergraphs, enriched-category-theory

In the paper ["Homotopy, homology, and persistent homology using closure spaces
Peter Bubenik, Nikola Milićević"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.10206) **HypGph** denote the category of hypergraphs and hypergraph homomorphisms.
In the paper [Decorated Cospans](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00872) in section 2.2 (alos in may other papers) they defined category of hypergraphs as follows:
Let (X) be an object in a symmetric monoidal category with a special commutative Frobenius structure $(X, \mu_X, \delta_X, \eta_X, \epsilon_X)$. The following equations hold:

\begin{align}
    \mu_{X \otimes Y} &= (\mu_X \otimes \mu_Y) \circ (1_X \otimes \sigma_{YX} \otimes 1_Y) \\
    \eta_{X \otimes Y} &= \eta_X \otimes \eta_Y \\
    \delta_{X \otimes Y} &= (1_X \otimes \sigma_{XY} \otimes 1_Y) \circ (\delta_X \otimes \delta_Y) \\
    \epsilon_{X \otimes Y} &= \epsilon_X \otimes \epsilon_Y
\end{align}

How are they same? Can someone explain?
here $\mu: X \to X \otimes X, \delta:X\otimes X \to X, \eta:I \to X, \epsilon: X \to I,$ and $\sigma$ is braiding.

Comment: Not conclusive but an idea: I remember reading somewhere that "for a while the dust hasn't quite settled on defining hypergraph categories." It's possible they _aren't_ equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The equations for $\mu_{X\otimes Y},\eta_{X\otimes Y}$ etc. that you write are rather the **definition** of a (commutative) Frobenius structure on $X\otimes Y$ based on the (commutative) Frobenius structures on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

In other words, the tensor product of two (commutative) Frobenius algebras in a symmetric monoidal category inherits a (commutative) Frobenius algebra structure. (Check that they indeed satisfy the Frobenius axioms).

Comment: yes, you are right, but I don't know how to relate the two definitions of the category of hypergraphs.